# Having trouble getting all the page numbers from a pdf file to output

Tags: python, pypdf

I'm having trouble getting all the page numbers from a pdf file.
this is my code!
I just get a one-page number that outputs I'm trying to get all the page numbers from my pdf file. How would I fix my code to get all the pdf page numbers? In total there are 20 pages.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Agsko.png)

Comment: Please post code as text, not an image of text.

Comment: also the error message... include it as text. [read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

My attempt looks something like this:

```
import PyPDF2
pdffileobj = open('test.pdf','rb')
pdfreader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdffileobj)
#extract the number of pages in the pdf and all text from the pdf

data = ''

#extract the text from the pdf
for i in range(pdfreader.numPages):
    pageobj = pdfreader.getPage(i)
    data += pageobj.extractText()
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/extract-text.html

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")
for page in reader.pages:
   print(page.extract_text())

print(f"pdf page count : {len(reader.pages)}")
```